# RabbitMQ HA deployment to avoid lost messages

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability, spring-amqp

I set up a 3 nodes RabbitMQ cluster with message mirroring on 2 nodes with the following policy:

```
ha-mode: exactly
ha-params: 2
ha-sync-mode: automatic
```

I'm doing some performance tests using Spring Boot and Spring AMQP. Basically I have Apache JMeter sending HTTP requests to a controller that publishes a message:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webhook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void webhook(@RequestBody(required = true) String webhookBody, HttpServletRequest request) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("exchange", "key", "message");
}
```

with the following configuration:

```
spring:    
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: rabbitmq-1:5672,rabbitmq-2:5672,rabbitmq-3:5672
```

I have configured the script to do a request every 100ms and while running I try to shutdown one node. The result is `AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException` and at least 8-9 failed requests. 
What other settings do you suggest to completely avoid failed responses in this case? Is it better to use a Layer 4 proxy like HAProxy / Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the `autoRecoverEnabled` on the underlying rabbit connection factory (it was true by default in 1.7.0); it is false again by default in 1.7.1.

The `RabbitTemplate` will recover the connection faster than the client's autoRecovery mechanism.

However, to avoid message loss you might want to consider adding a `RetryTemplate` to the `RabbitTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Gary Russel, upgrading to latest Spring Boot 1.5.2 did the trick, I have no lost messages on producer side.